# Projective Modules on PIDs

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

We are given a PID. Then we have to show that if F is a finitely generated free module of rank n, then a submodule M of F is free. This is fine. However, it then says to deduce that every finitely generated projective module is also free.

So, we have the result that F = L $\bigoplus$ $\alpha$(P), for some injective homomorphism $\alpha :  P \to F$, F a free module and L a submodule of F. I think I'm missing something here because this suggests to me straight away that if P is not free, F cannot be free and we don't need to know about L. However, I'm assuming that we need to show F is in fact finitely generated as P is finitely generated and therefore L can taken as free and, from this, that we have P is therefore free as well? Would anyone be able to help?

Edit: As soon as I posted this, I realised the proof used the following. As M is a submodule, F = M $\bigoplus$ ker($\pi$) (a projection) and that ker($\pi$) is free. So, are we meant to deduce that P is ker($\pi$) and therefore free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ a PID. $P$ be a finitely generated, projective module over $A$. Finitely generated over $A$ means, there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and some $A$-Module $K$, such that there's an exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow K \rightarrow A^n \rightarrow P \rightarrow 0$$
As $P$ is projective, this sequence is split exact. Or in other words, we can regard $P$ as a submodule of $A^n$ (which is by definition finitely generated free), as $A^n \cong K \oplus P$. Using the statement from the second sentence of your original post, we are done.

Comment: So, just to clarify then, as P is finitely generated and projective, we have that it is a submodule of some free finitely generated module and, therefore, the purpose of the first part of the question was to show that this makes P free? Why do we need to go to all this effort? The definition we're given is that for some free module F, F is the distinct sum of some module and $\alpha$(P). Take that module to be zero and we get straight away that some part of F is isomorphic P. Hence, if P is not free, F cannot be free. Why is this wrong?

Comment: Sorry about the notation btw, I just assumed that was the normal notation.

Comment: Firstly "some free module $F$" can not be chosen and generally does not have to be finitely generated.
Secondly, the "some module" in the direct sum generally is not $0$ (it is the $K$ from my post which can be anything).
Of course it follows a postiori from what we have just shown that over a PID things will become quite simple.

Comment: For an example look at the $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$-Module $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. It is projective, as $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, but it's not free. Also $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ certainly is not zero.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I didn't mean take it to be zero. I meant that it has zero in it so in particular, aren't we allowed to take all the elements 0 + $\alpha$(P)? Also, what do you mean by choosing F? We are just given that one exists (I don't know if this is true, but we are given the assumption that one such F exists) and is this not sufficient?

Comment: Thank you for the example, I'm going to have a look at it now to see if I can understand why my argument falls down.

Comment: In my answer it's just $K =$ "some module". I'm sorry, but I don't see where exactly lies your problem/misconception. I'm willing to help you more, but it would be helpful if you took some time to order your thoughts before posting again.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought they were ordered... It seems that I really don't understand then as I don't understand why they're confusing. We are given the following definition: P is finitely generated and projective means that for some finitely generated free module F and submodule L, F $\cong$ L $\bigoplus$ P. So, the idea was simply that we take the zero element in L and, if P is not free, we get a contradiction because there is some part of F that is not free. If that doesn't make sense, then never mind. I don't know how to explain it in a better way. :(

Comment: Actually, never mind. Thank you for your help, but I have this problem every time I come to algebra. I'm curious about the concepts and I never seem to be able to explain what I'm after so no-one seems able to help me. I'm going to take your example and just have a look through it to try and figure it out for myself. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: "So, the idea was simply that we take the zero element in L and, if P is not free, we get a contradiction because there is some part of F that is not free."
You are deducing this from the statement of your second sentence. As the example shows, in the case that the ring $A$ is not a PID this is not generally true.

Comment: Ahh! That makes perfect sense. Thank you!